# Can I use AWS ECR image directly in my Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

In a typical dockerfile, there is usually this line `From ubuntu:16.04` which enables pulling an image from docker repository.

Now I have built my own image repository:

[image]

The repositiory URI is: `1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycompany`

As seen in the above screenshot, I pushed an image to the server.

I run the following to ensure I have login to the ecr

```
> `aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2`
Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.14.
Login Succeeded
```

ECR login completes without error. Then I tried to build a new image:

```
> docker build -t rtf-converter . -f Dockerfile-rtf-converter 
Sending build context to Docker daemon 790.1 MB
Step 1/2 : FROM mycompany:latest
repository mycompany not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

Here is the content of the Dockerfile

```
FROM mycompany:latest
RUN apt-get install chef-zero
```

What is the right way to specify the repository properly in the `FROM` statement?

I am particularly confused by labels. What is a good convention of labeling?

Comment: It's just a docker registry, so yes. Just make sure dockerd is authenticated with the ECR repo properly.

Comment: I see. I have tried `asw ecr login` but still fail. I will revise the question to address this problem. I hope you don't mind I shift the goal poles

Comment: using the example above i wonder how/where to specify AWS credential? FROM 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycompany:latest

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The same pattern you use in `docker push` works:

```
FROM 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycompany:latest
```

Comment: For public images, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634619/how-to-make-ecs-repository-public